# Name property of UserControl or Control

Tags: visual-studio, properties, propertygrid

What is special about the Name property of a Control or UserControl that causes it to be displayed as "`(Name)`" inside the property grid within Visual Studio?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out [this article about design-time attributes in .NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164048.aspx). Specifically, I think you are looking for the `Browsable` attribute, which enables properties in Visual Studio's design-time properties dialogue.

If you have a property called `Name`, you'd declare it like this:

```
[Browsable(true)]
public string Name { /*...*/ }
```

You can set a lot more attributes, like `Description`, `DefaultValue` and `Category`, which will come in handy if you're planning on presenting your controls to other developers.

EDIT: To get the effect that you want, use both the `Browsable` and `ParenthesizePropertyName` attributes:

```
[Browsable(true)]
[ParenthesizePropertyName(true)]
public string Name { /*...*/ }
```

(Thanks to Ksempac from the comments for this.)

Since you didn't specify if you're using VB or C#, here's the same thing in VB:

```
<Browsable(true)> _
<ParenthesizePropertyName(true)> _
Public Property Name(Value As String) As String
' ...
End Property
```

EDIT 2:

I think you're wondering about why you would want to surround your property with parentheses in the first place, or perhaps what it means for a property's name to have parentheses around it.

You can find the answer to that [here](http://www.devx.com/dotnet/Article/32421/1763/page/2):

> Parenthesized properties are shown at the top of the window — or at the top of their category if the list is grouped by category

Basically, if a property is important, you want it to appear at the top of a sorted list, so you surround it with parentheses to indicate this.

Comment: Your link is good, but i guess he needs both Browsable and ParenthesizePropertyName set to get what he needs : he specified Name with parenthesis.

Comment: Please see edited question. I am asking what is the specialty of it.

Comment: @nils_gate: I don't understand what you mean by "specialty".

Comment: @nils_gate: See my latest edit. I think that's what you mean.